# how to close application with authentication error

Tags: android, authentication, kotlin, request, android-volley

I know activities will be ordered in a stack, if open a new activity, it will push at top of the stack and if press back button it will be popped from the stack,

my question is:

suppose I have 10 activities and each one gets some info from server, I send user's token to the server and based on token validate, I get the response, How can I handle that if the token was not validated and got authentication error from the server, close all these activities and redirect the user to the login page?
also, is there any way that handles this validation? like middlewares in the back-end?

by the way, I use volley for connecting to the server.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity#finishAffinity` will clear all the stack while finishing an activity.
But other stacks may remain filled. So, you may need `System#exit` but that solution is worse because it prevents application from destroying correctly.